# How to use js remove or rename first element of multi element with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6

Code:

```
<input class="date" value="${dateList}" /> 
<input class="date" value="${dateList}" />
```

I have 2 input with class=date, the value are from controller, everyday the values are different, how to delete or rename the class of first input class=date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:first`:

```
$("input:first-child").removeClass("date").addClass("differentDate");
```

Demo:

```js
$("input:first").removeClass("date").addClass("differentDate");
```

```css
.differentDate {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<input class="date" value="Date">
<input class="date" value="Date">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery selector:

```
$("input:first-child").removeClass("date"); 
$("input:first-child").addClass("myNewClass");
```

https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eq` in jquery ref https://api.jquery.com/eq/

```js
$('.date').eq(0).addClass('new').removeClass('date')
```

```css
.new
{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="date" value="a" /> 
<input class="date" value="b" />
```